# PHP shell_exec with lighttpd on Raspberry pi

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, php, lighttpd

I'm creating simple Wi-Fi scanning script on raspberry pi. for that I used lighttp web server and php. I can run php without any issues. but when I run shell script using php it not properly return the results. my code is like this

```
<?php
$ssidoutput = shell_exec('. /var/www/html/scanssid.sh');
sleep(3);
echo "<pre>$ssidoutput </pre>";
#var_dump($ssidoutput );
?>
```

but when I executing this I only get one SSID print on my web browser. but when I run shell script I can see full list of SSIDs on my terminal. I thought this is some kind of execution time issue and add sleep value. but that wont fix my issue. how to fix this. my shell script contain nothing but command to scan the SSIDs for Raspbian

Comment: Is that an actual typo of `ssidoutp` vs `ssidoutput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are facing this because "shell_exec" in php not able to read multi-line output.
easiest think to do is modify your script to print All SSID on single line. may be comma separated and then process in php to replace comma with new line.

Comment: No even  when i added | xargs to the shell script results are same, And when I execute command like ls -l it correctly print the multi-line output

Comment: can you try `| wc -l` in shell_exec to know whether problem is with timing or not.

Comment: there is other suggestion  remove sleep and try executing your command directly from shell_exec rather than encapsulate in shell script

Comment: also try `for i in {1..5}; do echo test output $i ; sleep 1; done` which will provide multi-line input which is delayed in time. if delay in time detected you can store the ssid values in a file (some shell_exec to do this) and then display the file output with next shell_exec.

Comment: all other commands work without any issues and print multiple lines of output. this command only print one line. I tried to add command directly to the PHP but not working. even when I try point output to txt file it only write one line. bit when I execute script manually it retrieve all the lines

Comment: iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID | xargs

Comment: Can you test this without xargs?

Comment: probably pipe may have some issue in shell_exec. try without it. read whole  string. and next command parse it to grep. NOTE: - I have tested on my php server it works fine with or without xargs. able to see list of SSID. So also check PHP server version and configuration.

Comment: I removed the pipe and still the issue is same. No matter how hard I tried I only getting only one SSID details. when pipe removed it retrieve first SSID details over 20 lines. but only that

Comment: I found that after I run command "iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID" on terminal I cant print values on browser for few times. but again after some time it again not working. why is that ?

Comment: it looks like bug in php or lighthttpd handling iwlist. Now what I can suggest that try different php server and lighthttpd. to verify the same you can additionally setup both server on some linux desktop. which may help finding exact issue. Preferably use same method and if possible same source files(in case cross compiled from source) to install php and httpd. if you find consistant behaviour on RPi and Desktop with same version, and other version working fine you can raise this bug.